# make out of new File() a folder

Tags: java, file, directory

I have to make File-Objects that i don't know if they exist at the moment. With a actual file no problem:

```
File file = new File("path+filename"); //File does not get generated which is fine.
file.isDirectory() //is false :)
```

So how do I make a File-Object which is a directory?

```
File file = new File("path+foldername"); 
file.isDirectory = true; //doesn't work oviously :(
```

Comment: Are you using Java 7+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets consider the following code. Here, intially we don't have a file or directory. That's why **exits()**,**isFile()** and **isDirectory()** returns false. But later on when we create a directory with **mkdir()** , **isDirectory** returns true as we have successfully created a directory.

```
    File file = new File("d:\\abc"); //This just creates a file object
    System.out.println(file.exists()); //This will return false
    System.out.println(file.isFile()); //This will return false
    System.out.println(file.isDirectory()); //This will return false

    file.mkdir(); //This will create a directory called abc
    System.out.println(file.exists()); //This will return true because a directory exists
    System.out.println(file.isFile()); //This will return false because we have created a directory called abc not a file
    System.out.println(file.isDirectory());//This will return true because we have just created a directory called abc
```

**EDIT:**

```
file.isDirectory()
```

will only return **true** when there exists a folder(directory). So, for example, if you already have a folder called **sample** at the following location **d:\sample**.  Now, create a file object called:

```
File file = new File("d:\\sample");
```

If you now call

```
file.isDirectory()  //Returns true
```

it will return true. Because the file object points to a valid and existent folder.

Comment: The problem is that i DON'T want to create the folder. I want just a object wich represents a folder and which returns true on `.isDirectory`

Answer (score 0):

The method to use is `.mdkir()` (or `.mkdirs()`).

However you'll need to check for the return code since they return `boolean`s...

But since this is 2015, I'll assume you use Java 7+. Therefore, ditch `File`, forget all about it, and use java.nio.file instead:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("elements", "of", "path", "here");

Files.createDirectory(path);
Files.createDirectories(path);
```